# Proper Queue threading technique in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, windows-services, queue

I wanted to implement a windows service that captures dropped flat delimited files to a folder for import to the database. What I originally envision is to have a FileSystemWatcher looking over new files imported and creating a new thread for importing.

I wanted to know how I should properly implement an algorithm for this and what technique should I use? Am I going to the right direction?

Comment: Why the service and special drop folder? Why not just drag a group of files onto a regular .exe and have it run, do the import to the database, then die?

Comment: @Reinderien: I imagine that the term "dropped" here does not refer to the process of a user dragging and dropping files, but rather some system producing files in a certain folder.

Comment: @Fredrik, you got it right. I did mention it's being dropped into a folder.

Comment: Okay, then what produces the files? Is there any way to control where the files go?

Comment: @Reinderien, another application exports those files to this server. the windows service process these files on this specific folder then parses, checks and saves important data.

Comment: If you can tell that application to choose a filename of the form \\someserver\PIPE\somenamedpipe where someserver is your own server and somenamedpipe is a pipe that you have open, then 1. you don't need to change any of the application code, and 2. it'll be faster and easier for everyone involved.

Comment: thank you, but i don't think your suggestion is related to my question. i'm not only saving information from the data in these files, i'm also processing them and saving it to the database.

Comment: I know. So instead of having to use FileSystemWatcher to do that, if you tell the source application to write to a filename that's actually a pipe, you can cut out a lot of overhead.

Comment: i don't think i have the luxury of knowing which pipes are open at the moment. I get your idea, its quite clever but i shall keep your suggestion in mind, thanks.

Comment: Thankfully, you do indeed know which pipes are open, because your Windows service would be creating them.

Comment: problem is, i have no control over this other application that creates the files. its clever but i don't think its applicable in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a thread per message will most likely be too expensive. If you can use .NET 4, you could start a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) for each message. That would run the code on a thread pool thread and thus reduce the overhead of creating threads.

You could also do something similar with [asynchronous delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb%28VS.71%29.aspx) if .NET 4 is not an option. However, the code gets a bit more complicated in that case. That would utilize the thread pool as well and save you the overhead of creating a new thread for each message.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however, we're still stuck using 3.5 sp1.

Comment: @Martin: That's okay. You could download the Reactive Extensions framework. It is basically a backport of the TPL.

Answer (score 1):

I developed an product like this for a customer. The service were monitoring a number of folders for new files and when the files were discovered, the files were read, processed (printed on barcode printers), archived and deleted.

We used a "discoverer" layer that discovered files using FileSystemWatcher or polling depending on environment (since FileSystemWatcher is not reliable when monitoring e.g. samba shares), a "file reader" layer and a "processor" layer.

The "discoverer" layer discovered files and put the filenames in a list that the "file reader" layer processed. The "discoverer" layer signaled that there were new files to process by settings an event that the "file reader" layer were waiting on.

The "file reader" layer then read the files (using retry functionality since you may get notifications for new files before the files has been completely written by the process that create the file).

After the "file reader" layer has read the file, a new "processor" thread were created using the ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem to process the file contents.

When the file has been processed, the original file were copied to an archive and deleted from the original location. The archive were also cleaned up regularly to keep from flooding the server. The archive were great for troubleshooting.

This has now been used in production in a number of different environments in over two years now and has proved to be very reliable.

Comment: thanks for this confirmation, lemme just wait for other inputs as well. your comment is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've fielded a service that does this as well. I poll via a timer whose elapsed event handler acts as a supervisor, adding new files to a queue and launching a configurable number of threads that consume the queue. Once the files are processed, it restarts the timer.

Each thread including the event handler traps and reports all exceptions. The service is always running, and I use a separate UI app to tell the service to start and stop the timer. This approach has been rock solid and the service has never crashed in several years of processing.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional approach is to create a finite set of threads (could be as few as 1) and have them watch a blocking queue. The code in the `FileSystemWatcher`<sup>1</sup> event handlers will enqueue work items while the worker thread(s) dequeue and process them.  It might look like the following which uses the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class which is available in .NET 4.0 or as part of the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) download.

*Note: The code is left short and concise for brevity. You will have to expand and harden it yourself.*

```
public class Example
{
  private BlockingCollection<string> m_Queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

  public Example()
  {
    var thread = new Thread(Process);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
  }

  private void FileSystemWatcher_Event(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    string file = GetFilePathFromEventArgs(args);
    m_Queue.Add(file);
  }

  private void Process()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      string file = m_Queue.Take();
      // Process the file here.
    }
  }
}
```

You could take advantage of the `Task` class in the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for a more modern and `ThreadPool`-like approach. You would start a new task for each file (or perhaps batch them) that needs to be processed. The only gotcha I see with this approach is that it would be harder to control the number of database connections being opened simultaneously. Its definitely not a showstopper and it might be of no concern.

<sup>1</sup><sub>The `FileSystemWatcher` has been known to be a little flaky so it is often advised to use a secondary method of discovering file changes in case they get missed by the `FileSystemWatcher`. Your mileage may vary on this issue.</sub>